# Why is it that increasing the molar mass generally increases the Entropy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

I've just found read that entropy increases through these reasons:

1. Changing the phase of the elements to a gas.
2. Increasing the **molar mass of that specific element** increases the entropy.

I understand the first one, but I can't grasp the second one.
Because naturally you would think that $\ce{H2}$ would have a higher entropy than $\ce{Ne}$ because one mole of it is generally lighter.

But however it is said that Ne has a **higher entropy because of its lower molar mass.**

**Why?**

Comment: The second statement is vague to me. Molar mass of what? Any random species? Two nonbranched alkanes? What?

Comment: **Molar mass of that specific element**.

Comment: If increasing the molar mass means bonding that specific element with other elements (form a compound), then the more the atoms are, the more is the possibility to have disorder.Although that second statement is quite blury...

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate? Just ***a*** sentence isn't going to clear things up.

Comment: You don't need to write an essey in order to be clear. I tried to help and that was my thought because, i repeat : the second statement is hard to understand. GOOD LUCK.

Comment: Why are you talking about changing of molar mass, not comparing of them?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but again, this isn't very helpful to the OP. Is their problem solved? I think not. (And that hardly needs asking from them.)

Comment: I'm sorry, we don't write here to immediately solve the problem, a thought you give  for something blury as this, can also be helpful. There is absolutely no need to be rude nor to tell me if my answer was helpful or not, votes are for that purpose.

Comment: Ndrina no one's being rude to you here. It's a feedback of why your answer might have been downvoted. Also, a thought isn't helpful. That's exactly what StackExchange tries to avoid: Giving out opinions rather than clear-cut answers. BTW, there was a VLQ flag on this answer, and I agreed with it. Opinions people have can be given out in comments, and, this can be a good comment. BUT, **this isn't an answer**.

Comment: I have converted this to a comment because it's not quite clear as to what the answer is responding to.  This is partly because the question is nebulous.  Consider commenting on the question to guide the asker to a better question before taking the time to answer.

Comment: The answer can certainly be edited and flagged for undeletion if it is improved, but I have preserved the comments here to keep the continuity of the conversation.

Comment: I just voted to close this question as unclear what you are asking, and gave it a downvote accordingly. The second statement has many possible interpretations, I think that it is ripped from the context of a textbook and in itself impossible to understand. I also do not understand if "But however it is said that Ne has a higher entropy because of its molar mass." is this your interpretation or the one of a book? In any case, I believe it is wrong.

Comment: I believe it is wrong as well, I do not understand why the textbook has said that. You can close it if it does not meet the criteria. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allowed energy levels for a particle of mass $m$ in a box of length $X$ are given by
$$E_i=\frac{h^2}{8mX^2}i^2\quad i=1,2,\ldots$$

(Already this equation gives a hint that an ideal gas of high molar mass has more thermally accessible translational states than a gas of low molar mass. Therefore, the molar entropy of a gas of high molar mass is greater.)

In this case, the partition function for translational motion in the $x$-direction is approximately
$$z=\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{1/2}X$$

The partition function for translational motion in three dimensions is
$$\begin{align}
z&=\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}XYZ\\
&=\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}V
\end{align}$$

For a system of $N$ particles

$$\begin{align}Z&=\frac{z^N}{N!}\\&=\frac{1}{N!}\left[\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}V\right]^N\end{align}$$

The statistical entropy is
$$\begin{align}
S &=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+k\ln Z\\
&=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+k\ln \frac{z^N}{N!}\\
&=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+kN\ln z-k\ln N!\\
&\approx\frac{U-U_0}{T}+kN\ln z-kN\ln N+kN\\
&=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+nR\ln z-nR\ln nN_\text{A}+nR\\
&=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+nR\ln\left[z\cdot\frac{1}{nN_\text{A}}\cdot \operatorname{e}\right] \\
&=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+n R \ln \left[\left(\frac{2\pi m k T}{h^2}\right)^{3/2} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{e}V}{nN_\text{A}}\right] \\
\end{align}$$

The internal energy of a monoatomic ideal gas is

$$U=U_0+\tfrac{3}{2}nRT$$

which leads to the Sackur–Tetrode equation:

$$\begin{align}
S &=\frac{U-U_0}{T}+nR\ln\left[\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{e}V}{nN_\text{A}}\right]\\
&=\tfrac{3}{2}nR+nR\ln\left[\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{e}V}{nN_\text{A}}\right]\\
&=nR\left\{\ln\left[\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{e}V}{nN_\text{A}}\right]+\tfrac{3}{2}\right\}\\
&=nR\ln\left[\left(\frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2}\right)^{3/2} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{e}^{5/2}V}{nN_\text{A}}\right]
\end{align}$$

This equation implies that the entropy $S$ of a monoatomic ideal gas depends on the mass $m$.

Comment: Interesting answer. Does the relationship between entropy and molar mass really depend on the Schrödinger equation solution for a particle in a box, or could it be obtained without having to delve into quantum mechanics (perhaps at the expense of not deducing the proportionality constant)?

Comment: But to be fair, is there anyway you can compress all that and express it in English or some sort of concepts that go together to get this final answer?